# Dynamic creation of objects and adding them to a linked list

Tags: c++, list, dynamic, linked-list

It's about a C++ console game with tanks that shoots shells. The problem is about the tank shell part.
I want to create an object of class PlayerTankShell and add it to a linked list every time the space button is pressed. How can i do that ?

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

#define ATTACK  32

class PlayerTankShell
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int speed;
    bool isExist;

public:
    PlayerTankShell(bool exists)
    {
        isExist = exists;
    }
    bool getExistense()
    {
        return isExist;
    }
};

int main()
{
    char input;
    input = getch();

    if (input == ATTACK)
    {
        // Here create an object and add it to the linked list
    }

    // My test so far:
    PlayerTankShell *s1 = new PlayerTankShell(1);
    PlayerTankShell *s2 = new PlayerTankShell(1);
    PlayerTankShell *s3 = new PlayerTankShell(1);

    list<PlayerTankShell> listShells;

    listShells.push_back(*s1);
    listShells.push_back(*s2);
    listShells.push_back(*s3);

    list<PlayerTankShell>::iterator i;

    for (i = listShells.begin(); i != listShells.end(); i++)
    {
        cout << "exists=" << i->getExistense() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As side notes, you should define your `PlayerTankShell()` constructor `explicit`, and the `getExistense()` method can be marked as `const`.

Comment: How exactly to do that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like:

```
std::list<PlayerTankShell> shells;
```

Then you can add to it with:

```
shells.push_back(PlayerTankShell(true))
```

Comment: Very nice. Thanks!
Later i will need to iterate over them to print them on the screen.

Comment: Just be careful if you put any pointers/complex objects in there, since your PlayerTankShell has no copy constructor and it's easy to end up copying when you add/remove from collections.

Comment: If they go out of the screen i will mark them for deletion with i->setExistence(false); My question is how to remove them from the linked list without loosing the iterator, maybe something like this: i = listShells.erase(i); Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. std::list::erase returns a bidirectional iterator that points to the list element following the erased element.

Answer (score 0):

If you want *pointers* to `PlayerTankShell` stored in the list, you may want to use some **smart pointer** template class, like `shared_ptr` (if those `PlayerTankShell` are shared also in other parts of the code, they will be destructed as soon as the reference count reaches zero, i.e. with STL containers and `shared_ptr` you have a "**deterministic garbage collector**"):

```
// List of smart pointers to PlayerTankShell
list<shared_ptr<PlayerTankShell>> shells;

// Add new PlayerTankShell to the list
shells.push_back( make_shared<PlayerTankShell>(true) );
```